# Besides placeholder substitution what other features should a templating system include?

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

Just what are the minimum essential features of a templating system besides the obvious placeholder substitution?

Give examples of libraries if you wish and what makes them cool and what bits about them suck and maybe should not be there...

Comment: A bit on the subjective side, no? Maybe better suited for Programmers?

Comment: Sure why not isnt SO for programmers ?

Comment: This question seems to be subjective. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would really be a better place for it.

Comment: So what if its subjective. After you learn to how to read documentation, design the next layer above is all subjective. Do you want to learn from others or do you want more boring lame homework questions or q that are in the doco ? Is SO for programmers or for newbies who dont have a clue and are too lazy to try ?

Answer (score 0):

- Ability to generate ODT, PDF, RTF, HTML, MS Word, MS Excel, and plain text files from templates
- i18n support
- no need to be a replacement for JSP etc. we have enough of those
- ability to generate source code (Java 5 or more)
- Merge capability
- dynamic loading of templates
- ability to include templates
- 1 single jar with no other dependencies (specially commons-logging)

[Here are](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines) some of the available templating engines in Java. Velocity, FreeMaker and StringTemplate, I believe are most popular. You can have the best of all of them.

Comment: Ability to generate source ? Is this a request to get the "compiled" form for extra speed ? Generating multiple target formats is a layer above templating, i was using temlpating to mean the generation of a String. You can then use that String inside a PDF, JSP, exception message, log it etc.

Comment: Last time i saw velocity i was told it includes stacktraces rather than throwing some exception that escapes if something goes wrong when including a variable. That just sucks.

Comment: How do you define merge ? Is just placeholder substitution just merging under a different name ?

Comment: @mP - We also use Velocity for generating source code based on a meta model. and this is a very good use case for any templating framework. Merge = ability to combine multiple templates at runtime.